# Entity Framework 6 not updating from database correctly in VS 2019

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a .NET MVC web app using Entity Framework 6 to manage a model from a SQL Server database. I've been using VS 2017 to develop everything so far, making changes to the database, and updating the model after those changes are made. When I switched to VS 2019 and attempted this, only the model and diagram of the model were updated. The classes generated by EF were not updated with the changes from the database. Does VS 2019 handle EF models differently than 2017?

Comment: It appears this has been fixed in version 16.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread on VS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/438312/vs-2019-preview2-after-saving-edmx-code-is-not-gen.html), it will be [fixed in VB2019.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/705), in the meantime there's a workaround:

1. Save the .edmx file
2. Expand the .edmx file in Solution Explorer
3. For each .tt files inside it, right-click and choose Run Custom Tool.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm experiencing exactly the same issue.  The EDMX file gets updated as expected, but additional fields aren't being added to the generated class...

Reopening the project in VS 2017 works, suggesting that something has changed within VS itself.